# How to install softkeyboard fixes for Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, android-softkeyboard

I tried downloading both recommended keyboard managers but I get an error that:

```
NU1202  Package IQKeyboardManager.Touch 4.0.1 is not compatible with monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1). Package IQKeyboardManager.Touch 4.0.1 supports: xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
```

And I'm not sure what to do next. I don't want to dig myself into some hole.

Here were the previously recommended keyboard managers:

```
xamarin ios binding [https://github.com/TheEightBot/Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager][1]

Xamarin Nuget: [https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager/][1]
```

Comment: That package is for Xamarin.iOS projects, not Android.

Comment: OUCH!!!!!!!! OMG!!!! Thank you very much. OUCH.

Comment: Please post the solve method to answer, it will help others who have similar issue